# how to purchase from amazon using Paypal?

Tags: paypal, israel

I live out side united states , and have **30K** $ in my **Paypal** account.

I need to purchase from amazon.com using my Paypal account .

I see that amazon.com just accept bank cards , 
but if i need to use my local bank visa then i should pay about **3000$** fees .

How could i purchase using my Paypal account and pay max **0.01%** fees ?

Comment: You live outside the US, but used a US tag. Both PayPal and Amazon operate in many countries, the US tag is misleading.

Answer (score 2):

From [PayPal's Q&A](https://www.paypal.com/selfhelp/article/Withdraw-Money-FAQ2316)

> - PayPal Debit MasterCard
>
> The PayPal Debit MasterCard is the fastest way to withdraw money from
>   your PayPal account.

As a MasterCard, Amazon is beside the point. You can use it at any store that takes MasterCard Debit cards. And there would be no fees at all. It's your money.

Comment: thanks again, but it seems that the paypal debit master card is just available for united states paypal accounts .

Comment: do you have other suggestions ? it will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this, you would need to purchase an Amazon gift card from another online vendor that accepts PayPal and then use the Amazon gift card on the Amazon site. There are dozens (if not hundreds) of sites that sell Amazon gift cards online that accept PayPal.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but all of them don't accept international transactions. if you are familiar with one, please tell me , it will be highly appreciated .

Comment: @adamkaplan [eGifter does this.](https://www.egifter.com/credit-card/amazon-gift-card-credit-card) Though I'm not sure about the international bit.

Comment: thanks again, but egifter doesn't accept international payment

Comment: Does a PayPal transaction count as "international" in the first place?